# Unable to register push notification templates with Xamarin Azure Messaging component on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

I have a Xamarin Android app that is using Azure Notification Hubs with the Xamarin Azure Messenging component.  If I just register the device with some tags, based on the sample code, everything works correctly.  If I register the device with a named template, the registration method throws a NotificationHubException exception.  The equivalent code for Xamarin.iOS works just fine.

This code works:

```
protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
{
    if (hub != null)
    {
        List<string> tags = new List<string>();

        tags.Add("test1");
        tags.Add("test2");

        hub.Register(registrationId, tags.ToArray());
    }
}
```

This code throws an exception

```
protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
{
    if (hub != null)
    {
        List<string> tags = new List<string>();

        tags.Add("test1");
        tags.Add("test2");

        var alerts = "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"$(message)\",\"title\":\"$(title)\"}}";
        hub.RegisterTemplate(registrationId, alerts, "alerts", tags.ToArray());
    }
}
```

When the RegisterTemplate is called, it throws the WindowsAzure.Messaging.NotificationHubException exception with the following packet

```
<Error>
    <Code>400</Code>
    <Detail>Encountered unexpected character 'a'. TrackingId:bcecaffa-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX,TimeStamp:3/12/2015 3:55:06 PM</Detail>
</Error>
```

Am I calling RegisterTemplate correctly?

Comment: I want to use this registerTemplate method, but I am not getting what is first parameter 'registrationId', can you tell what should I send in first parameter? Is that GCM registration id or any other device id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've swapped parameter 2 and 3 I believe. 
Try this:

```
hub.RegisterTemplate(registrationId, "alerts", alerts, tags.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.